# Get comments without api in Instagram with Python

Tags: python, instagram

I need to get the photo comments a particular hashtag, however, from what I've read, it is required that this API sandbox outside.

As requested by an application in production, I do not have, but I am development / test it.

It occurred to me get feedback without the API, but not know how to implement it.

You can help me please?.

Thanks.